# Highcharts, stop the rendering of dynamic spline graph

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, graph, highcharts

I created a Dynamical Spline Graph in Angular, following the HighCharts documentation.

I want the chart to stop rendering when a button is clicked.

**HTML:**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'spline',
        animation: Highcharts.svg,
        events: {
            load: function () {

                // set up the updating of the chart each second
                var series = this.series[0];
                setInterval(function () {
                        y = Math.random();
                    series.addPoint(y, true, true);
                }, 1000);
            }
        }
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Live random data'
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Value'
        },
        plotLines: [{
            value: 0,
            width: 1,
            color: '#808080'
        }]
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Random data',
        data: [12, 27.5, 31.4, 32.1 ]
    }]
});
```

**Example of the chart on JSFiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/cau4mgfp/2/

Comment: The Graph is plotting the data dynamically, by fetching new data from a sensor.

I want the chart to stop rendering when a button is clicked, because when this happens the app also stops getting new data from the sensor.

Do not understand how this could be achieved, and also can't not seem to find a solution for this anywhere.

All the help would be much appreciated!! Thank You!

Comment: hi check this demo http://jsfiddle.net/nwet22z4/ using `clearInterval`

Answer (score 1):

It can be stopped using `clearInterval()`

```
function stopFn() {
  clearInterval(interVal);
}

function startFn() {
  var series = chart.series[0];
  interVal = setInterval(function() {
    y = Math.random();
    series.addPoint(y, true, true);
  }, 1000);
}
```

```js
var interVal;
var chart;
chart = new Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'spline',
    animation: Highcharts.svg,
    events: {
      load: function() {

        // set up the updating of the chart each second
        var series = this.series[0];
        interVal = setInterval(function() {
          y = Math.random();
          series.addPoint(y, true, true);
        }, 1000);
      }
    }
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Live random data'
  },
  yAxis: {
    title: {
      text: 'Value'
    },
    plotLines: [{
      value: 0,
      width: 1,
      color: '#808080'
    }]
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Random data',
    data: [12, 27.5, 31.4, 32.1]
  }]
});

function stopFn() {

  clearInterval(interVal);
}

function startFn() {

  var series = chart.series[0];
  interVal = setInterval(function() {
    y = Math.random();
    series.addPoint(y, true, true);
  }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
<button onclick="stopFn()">
Stop
</button>
<button onclick="startFn()">
Start
</button>
```